# X-axis is not shown when using numeric values

Tags: chart.js

I use an array of objects as data for my dataset. The problem is I can use only string values for x property. Otherwise X-axis is not shown.

[numeric Xs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNl5G.png)

But with string values everything works fine

[string Xs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7qbJ.png)

It confuses me a lot because they use numeric values in [the official docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your x axis is a [category axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html); why is that, depends on some factors you didn't specify, it's possible the type of the chart is `"line"` which has default category x axis; you could force the axis to be linear by  setting the `options.scales.x.type` to `"linear"`, or you could set the type of the cart to `"scatter"`.

Comment: In any case, you should provide much more information, what is called a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to get effective help on this site. Don't expect there's an expert here that has memorized all the combinations of options for a library, and all possible misuses of them; people need to run code to identify a problem and also to confirm that their solution is right and deserves to be posted as an answer.